# Convertir una variable double a float

Tags: android, android-studio

Recién empiezo en esto de la programación en Android studio, actualmente necesito convertir el contenido de una variable double a float, he visto algunos ejemplos aquí y no consigo eliminar el error, sera que me pueden ayudar?

Todo esto porque necesito guardar el valor de una variable double y el método preferences no me permite guardar un double.

```
   if(bAngle != 0.00){
            bAngleF = bAngle;
            bAngleL = (float) bAngle;
            myEditor.putFloat("Bangulo", bAngleL);
            myEditor.commit();
        } else{
            bLengthF = (double)myPreferences.getFloat("Bangulo",0);
        }
```

el error me lo da en la linea

```
            bAngleL = (float) bAngle;
```

me dice que el tipo es inconvertible.  bAngleL es una variable de tipo float y bAngle es double.

Comment: Es mejor guardarlo como cadena y cuando vayas a usarlo haces un *cast* mediante `Double.parseDouble()`. No te aconsejo convertirlo a float, podrías tener problemas de precision, perder datos, etc.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @A.Cedano, lo tomaré en consideración.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes convertir primeramente la variable tipo double a float usando  `.floatValue()`:

```
bAngleL = bAngle.floatValue();
```

y este valor guardarlo en tu preferencia:

```
myEditor.putFloat("Bangulo", bAngleL);
myEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, con esto resolví el problema!

Comment: Excelente @Odoardo recuerda marcar como solucion la respuesta que ayuda a solucionar el problema, revisa [tour] , saludos!.